# Regex, ignore last match in group

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want to capture in the line below only the world

"ArticleDAO"

- it.foo.burp.ArticleDAOLocal
- it.foo.burp.ArticleDAO

Note:
it.foo.burp can be any package, and the class name can be everything that finishes or not with word "Local".

if Local exists, than must be omitted.

This is my regex:

```
(.*\.)([\w]+)(?:Local)?
```

this works for the the second example, but not for the first one because it captures also "Local" ($1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with an *optional* match and a lazy quantifier:

```
(\w+?)(?:Local)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ilJ2Rx/2)

Your match is available in captured group # 1.

- `(\w+?)`: will match 1 or more word characters (non-greedy)
- `(?:Local)?$`: Will match optional `Local` before line end.